# Gastroenteritis virus causing mutation of the Enterochromaffin cells

Tags: neuroscience, neurotransmitter, literature, gastroenterology, neuromodulation

I am working on the solution to a worldwide problem: IBS or chronic diarrhea following a viral gastroenteritis infection. I think I have an answer. The only missing piece to the puzzle I found in a research paper discussing the genetic mutation of the Enterochromaffin cells by a gastroenteritis virus. I believe the paper was from Japan.  I had it, but I lost it.  Any help in finding this paper again would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3126904/) can be a jumping-off point?

Comment: `Gastroenteritis virus + chromaffin + mutation` gives no result on pubmed. I tried all combinations and variations. The closest is [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21779163) article.